# Akka http redirect but change method from POST to GET

Tags: akka-http

I have endpoint using POST method ( registering token for example ), after job done I want to redirect client to "/" url, but using GET not POST.
How to achieve this ?

For now I have:

```
redirect("/", StatusCodes.PermanentRedirect)
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want in this case is not a redirect with status code `PermanentRedirect`, but rather `SeeOther` (303). So you would have instead: `redirect("/", StatusCodes.SeeOther)`

You can check in [RFC 7231, section 6.4.4: 303 See Other](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4) that this guarantees the behavior you describe.